# find element by attribute value within a subset

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to find the next image, based on the current image path. It's for some customized lightbox and jquery 1.3.2. My html:

```
<div id="feat_screenshots">
    <a class="lightbox" href="/images/features/1.gif"><img title="Image 1" alt="Image 1" src="/images/features/1.gif"></a>
    <a class="lightbox" href="/images/features/2.gif"><img title="Image 2" alt="Image 2" src="/images/features/2.gif"></a>
    <a class="lightbox" href="/images/features/3.gif"><img title="Image 3" alt="Image 3" src="/images/features/3.gif"></a>
</div>
```

and my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.lightbox").click(function(){
        var img_src = $(this).attr("href");
        getNextImage(img_src);
    });
}

function getNextImage(curPath)
{
    var $picset = $("a.lightbox");
    alert($($picset).find("img[src=\'/images/features/1.gif\']").attr("title"));
    alert($($picset).find("img[src$=\'/images/features/1.gif\']").attr("title"));
    alert($($picset).find("img[src=curPath]").attr("title"));
    alert($($picset).find("img[src$=curPath]").attr("title"));
/*
    to be continued...
*/
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out what works and what not. I'm using .attr("title") here only for debugging to test which picture i found.

If i pass in '/images/features/1.gif' to getNextImage() only the 2nd alert returns the correct title; all the others come back as 'undefined'.

So my question is: What is the correct syntax to use my variable `curPath` here to get an element? Nothing i tried works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curPath` is a variable, so you need to concatenate it to the selector

```
$($picset).find("img[src='" + curPath + "']").attr("title")
```

Comment: $picse is always the first <a>

Answer (score 1):

Is curPath is varibale???

So try this one.

alert($($picset).find("img[src="+ curPath + "]").attr("title"));

Comment: $picse is always the first <a>

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.lightbox").click(function(){
        var img_src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    });
}
```

and the thing your `getNextImage` works for only the first element

you set

```
 var $picset = $("a.lightbox");
```

this is always your first

```
 <a>
```

if you really want pass to another function you can do this

```
 getNextImage($(this),img_src);
```

then in function get it

```
function getNextImage(current_anchor,curPath)
{
    var img_src = $(current_anchor).find("img[src='" + curPath + "']").attr("title");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if all you really want to do is get the next `a` tag , why not use the `next()` function?

```
$("a.lightbox").click(function(){
    var nextImage = $(this).next();
});
```